# Load different design on same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I don't know if this is possible or can be done but i have heard and seen that people have achived tis using AJAX and also iFrames.

At the moment i have a simple vertical bar i have created and designed down the left hand side of the page:

[image]

What I want to happen is when I click one of the items which is coded like:

```
 <div id='cssmenu'>
        <ul>
            <li class='active'><a href='index.html'><span>Home</span></a></li>
            <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Products</span></a></li>
                <li><a href='#'><span>Product 1</span></a></li>
                <li><a href='#'><span>Product 2</span></a></li>
                <li><a href='#'><span>Product 2</span></a></li>
                <li><a href='#'><span>Product 2</span></a></li>
                <li><a href='#'><span>Product 2</span></a></li>
                <li><a href='#'><span>Product 2</span></a></li>
                <li><a href='#'><span>Product 2</span></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

When i click a different side bar link I want a different design or page to load up but inside the same web form

Is this possible and if so how can this be achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

amusing that you have a div with `id="content"` which content should be loaded in it:

```
$('.cssmenu').find('a').click(
    function(e)
    {
         e.preventDefault();
         $('#content').load($(this).attr('href'));
    }
);
```

using button:

```
<input type="button" value="load content" id="loadtest">
```

and the script:

```
$('#loadtest').click(function(){$('#content').load('test.aspx');});
```

Comment: Mobayen Khiaba Do I have to create different ASPX pages or if there a way to just up a different design?

Comment: you should design separate aspx pages (that does not have html, body tags as already exist in your current page) or you can create a single page and manage content using switch-case and sending the case using query string: `<a href="items.aspx?id=1">Product 1</a><a href="items.aspx?id=2">Product 2</a>`....

Comment: I think the easiest way would be create different pages, would this take up alot of space as I'm creating alot more pages?

Comment: code pages do not use much space do they? especially that they will contain just the content that needs to load. for example a page might have only a DIV tag with some content in it

Comment: What about if I load up a DIV depending on button click is that possible?

Comment: yes of course, have a look at answer. I edited it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55323/discussion-between-ashkan-mobayen-khiabani-and-user3129331).